# Get current MethodBase through reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Can I get the current method's MethodInfo somehow?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()
```

Found it myself after some screwing around with the reflection namespace...

Comment: Hehe. You just beat me to it! Note that this returns a MethodBase object, not a MethodInfo. But that may be just what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod` static method.